# Flex chart with scroll and zoom - similar to Google Finance charts

Tags: apache-flex

I am looking to create an adobe air/flex chart, which works and looks exactly like:-

http://flex.amcharts.com/examples/stock_chart_example

Now, I can't afford to pay for amcharts license.. and the free version includes a backlink to amcharts.

Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doug McCune](http://dougmccune.com/blog/) has a drill-down [google-finance-esque charting example](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/03/22/why-i-love-flex-charting-example/) with [source code](http://dougmccune.com/flex/chartComparison/srcview/index.html) and [demo](http://dougmccune.com/flex/chartComparison/):

[image: chart-compare]

Comment: Is there something similar for the Spark architecture?

Comment: Flex Data Visualization SDK is Halo.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I'm looking for a compatible charting engine for Flex4, ideally pure AS based because I'm targeting the mobile platform.

Comment: That would be awesome - I haven't seen any open source project that compares to Flex Data Vis SDK.  Performance for small data sets is actually surprisingly good for mobile; however, I too would be interested in pure ActionScript alternatives.

Comment: You can quickly scribble basic charts using the spark path (http://coenraets.org/blog/2010/09/building-lightweight-mobile-ready-charts-with-fxg/), and I already made a small engine with gridlines, but still nothing fancy and far from complete and actually ready to publish. Something like the demo you showed above would be really nice, especially with the zoom/scroll indicators below. But I searched for countless hours already, no luck yet.

Comment: This one is spark based: http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Flexicious-30-Release-Dashboard-and-Charting-Edition.aspx